# Can pop-out floats be installed post-manufacture on all helicopters?

Tags: helicopter

I have seen in many helicopters pop-out floats installed.

Are they the optional, or do they come pre-installed with every helicopter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pop out floats can be installed easily on any helicopter with Tubular landing skid type landing gear. Its essentially an auto-inflatable tube attached to the landing gear. Have a look at this:

[image]

Comment: How do they get inflated when in contact with water? Do pilot have an option for this?

Comment: Yes. For obvious reasons, or else they'd get inflated on a land touchdown as well

Comment: @NitinG: Might be either, depends on type. (Obviously sensor that detects being immersed in water won't trigger on land)

Comment: in the copter I've flown with pop-out floats (R44), there is a nitrogen bottle under the left seat, with a cable-operated valve that goes to a collective-mounted handle that can be operated without taking your hand off the collective. the handle has a safety on it, which is disabled "feet wet" and enabled "feet dry". here's a photo: http://www.helicopter-redeye.com/images/F%20View%20from%20above.jpg

Comment: downvoted b/c popout floats CANNOT be installed on any copter. they can only go on copters for which an STC has been developed

Comment: I was told by an avid flier that you get "Customized" popout floats, which need to be bolted (tied) in order to be deployed. No STC needed.